# convert stop watch time to seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a stopwatch on my website I would like to take the result after the stop button is clicked and convert it into seconds.

is it possible to calculate the given time and turn it into seconds only with javascript or jquery?

after the convert, I would like to send the value into my database

I can  see the result in my console

```js
var ss = document.getElementsByClassName('stopwatch');

[].forEach.call(ss, function (s) {
    var currentTimer = 0,
        interval = 0,
        lastUpdateTime = new Date().getTime(),
        start = s.querySelector('button.start'),
        stop = s.querySelector('button.stop'),
        reset = s.querySelector('button.reset'),
        mins = s.querySelector('span.minutes'),
        secs = s.querySelector('span.seconds'),
        cents = s.querySelector('span.centiseconds');

    start.addEventListener('click', startTimer);
    stop.addEventListener('click', stopTimer);
    reset.addEventListener('click', resetTimer);

    function pad (n) {
        return ('00' + n).substr(-2);
    }

    function update () {
        var now = new Date().getTime(),
            dt = now - lastUpdateTime;

        currentTimer += dt;

        var time = new Date(currentTimer);

        mins.innerHTML = pad(time.getMinutes());
        secs.innerHTML = pad(time.getSeconds());
        cents.innerHTML = pad(Math.floor(time.getMilliseconds() / 10));

        lastUpdateTime = now;
    }

    function startTimer () {
        if (!interval) {
            lastUpdateTime = new Date().getTime();
            interval = setInterval(update, 1);
        }
    }

    function stopTimer () {
        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = 0;
    }

    function resetTimer () {
        stopTimer();

        currentTimer = 0;

        mins.innerHTML = secs.innerHTML = cents.innerHTML = pad(0);

    }
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".stop").click(function(){
        var m = $('#min').html();
        var s = $('#sec').html();
        var ms = $('#msec').html();
        console.log(m,s,ms);
        
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Stopwatch</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="stopwatch">
    <div class="controls">
        <button class="start">Start</button>
        <button id="stp" class="stop">Stop</button>
        <button class="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
    <div class="display">
        <span id="min" class="minutes" value="">00</span><span id="sec" class="seconds" value="">00</span><span id="msec" class="centiseconds" value="">00</span>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="watch/stopwatch.js"></script>

<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should add HTML as well so we can debug it.

Comment: i have updated the post

Comment: I'm not sure I understand where do you have difficulties here? You already have the value of span elements for minutes, seconds and milliseconds. Can't you just take those values and store them in a new variable? Was that the question? If you need a way to do this, let me know and I'll write the code. Btw, how do you intend to send/store milliseconds on the server? In the form of floating number? For example: 19.34s?

Comment: `1 millisecond = 0.001 seconds` so go ahead and apply this to your code and it should all work.

Comment: Btw, ID is called "msec" (millisecond = 1/1000s), but the class on the same element is **centisecond** which is 1/100s. You should probably fix that.

Comment: thank you for your replays. I will make myself more clear: first of all I don't need to calculate the milliseconds, I have the math calc but I all ways get a 0 at the end that I don't need S + (m * 60) any idea how to get read of the 0 at the end?

Comment: If I understood correctly, this is what you need. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed
 Btw, you should update your question - it's still very confusing. Please let me know if this one solves your problem and note that you need to convert that string into a Number first. (basically, `toFixed(0)`)

Comment: check this codepen [ https://codepen.io/vivekamin/pen/jQxdPJ?page=2& ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your second function (the one logging the values), you can just perform some simple mathematics to get a total number of seconds:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".stop").click(function(){
        var m = $('#min').html();
        var s = $('#sec').html();
        var ms = $('#msec').html();
        console.log(m,s,ms);
        var total = (parseInt(m) * 60) + parseInt(s);
        console.log(total + "." + ms);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly there are 2 questions:
1) How to calculate time and show it? And you already calculated time in seconds, so to display it properly just change HTML to:

```
<span>Min: </span><span id="min" class="minutes" value="">00</span><span> Sec: </span><span id="sec" class="seconds" value="">00</span><span> Msec: </span><span id="msec" class="centiseconds" value="">00</span>
```

2) To pass data from js to your "database" (presume that you actually mean server side) you can use ajax (https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)
[Pass variable string from javascript to php using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52743639/pass-variable-string-from-javascript-to-php-using-ajax)